# Will I still get weapon discounts in Ratchet & Clank 3 with a Ratchet & Clank 1 new game+ save?

Tags: ratchet-and-clank, ratchet-and-clank-up-your-arsenal

In *Ratchet and Clank 3: Up your Arsenal*, it's possible to get an "employee discount" at Gadgetron weapons vendors if you have a save file from *Ratchet & Clank* 1 present on the memory card.

The save file has to be beyond the point in the game where you become a Gadgetron employee (i.e win the hoverboard race at Gadgetron HQ to become a spokesperson for Gadgetron hoverboards).

My question is: if I start the New Game+ mode on Ratchet and Clank 1, overwriting the save at the end of the game, does the NG+ save still count as holding an employee discount for the purposes of Ratchet and Clank 3?

Or must I maintain a separate save at the end of the game? (at least until after the hoverboard race in the NG+ save).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Keep two saves

A fresh New Game+ save does not count for the purposes of the discount in Ratchet & Clank 3.

I'm guessing the logic only checks story progress, so if you overwrite your game save at the end of the game with the NG+ save, you won't be considered a Gadgetron employee in Ratchet & Clank 3. Not until you re-complete the Gadgetron HQ hoverbard challenge on the NG+ save.

Comment: (And yes, I just discovered this the hard way)